# Python nested for loop and if statement trouble

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, nested

I am looking to build a dictionary of list that meet the following criteria:
Item0 in list1 == Item0 in list2 and Item1 in list1 == Item1 in list2 and Date2 in list1 < Date2 in list2.

Running the code as is gives me one list in the dict. The one list is the same even if I change the if statement to > instead of <.

Everything prior to this(see below) looks correct:
"for li in Liststr2:
for lr in Liststr1A:
if lr[0] == li[0] and lr[1] == li[1] and lr[2] > li[2]:"

Also "lr[2] & li[2]" are dtype <M8[ns] if that makes a difference.

```
df = {'Position': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 1, 7: 2, 8: 1, 9: 1, 10: 1, 11: 2, 12: 1, 13: 2, 14: 1, 15: 2, 16: 1, 17: 2, 18: 1, 19: 2, 20: 1}, 'Location': {0: 'AB1', 1: 'AB2', 2: 'AB3', 3: 'AB4', 4: 'AB4', 5: 'AB4', 6: 'AB4', 7: 'AB4', 8: 'AB4', 9: 'AB2', 10: 'AB5', 11: 'AB4', 12: 'AB4', 13: 'AB6', 14: 'AB6', 15: 'AB6', 16: 'AB6', 17: 'AB6', 18: 'AB6', 19: 'AB1', 20: 'AB1'}, 'DATE': {0: Timestamp('2021-05-22 18:00:00'), 1: Timestamp('2021-05-21 13:00:00'), 2: Timestamp('2021-05-24 12:23:00'), 3: Timestamp('2021-05-23 12:25:00'), 4: Timestamp('2021-05-23 12:25:00'), 5: Timestamp('2021-05-23 12:25:00'), 6: Timestamp('2021-05-23 12:25:00'), 7: Timestamp('2021-05-23 12:25:00'), 8: Timestamp('2021-05-23 12:25:00'), 9: Timestamp('2021-05-21 18:00:00'), 10: Timestamp('2021-05-21 18:00:00'), 11: Timestamp('2021-05-24 14:08:00'), 12: Timestamp('2021-05-24 14:08:00'), 13: Timestamp('2021-05-24 16:35:00'), 14: Timestamp('2021-05-24 16:35:00'), 15: Timestamp('2021-05-24 16:35:00'), 16: Timestamp('2021-05-24 16:35:00'), 17: Timestamp('2021-05-24 19:48:00'), 18: Timestamp('2021-05-24 19:48:00'), 19: Timestamp('2021-05-25 23:45:00'), 20: Timestamp('2021-05-25 23:45:00')}, 'Item Numbers': {0: '788-33', 1: '07-1', 2: '5214-3', 3: '003', 4: '003', 5: '009J', 6: '009J', 7: '009J', 8: '009J', 9: '07-1', 10: '68-302', 11: '6-5213', 12: '6-5214', 13: '1-801', 14: '1-801', 15: '1-801', 16: '1-801', 17: '4-008', 18: '4-008', 19: 'A-001', 20: 'A-001'}}
finaltemp = []
Finallist = {}
str1Temp = []
str2Temp = []
NaValues = []
Liststr2 = []
Liststr1 =  []
Listna = []
n = 0

for col, row in df.iterrows() :
    col1Temp = row['col1']
    col2Temp = row['col2']
    col3temp = row['col3']
    col4Temp = row['col4']
    if col4Temp == None:
        NaValues = [col1Temp, col3temp, col2Temp]
        Listna.append(NaValues)
    if col4Temp == 'str1':
        str1Temp = [col1Temp, col3temp, col2Temp]
        Liststr1.append(str1Temp)
    if col4Temp == 'str2':
        str2Temp = [col1Temp, col3temp, col2Temp]
        Liststr2.append(str2Temp)
    for li in Liststr2:
        for lr in Liststr1:
            if lr[0] == li[0] and lr[1] == li[1] and lr[2] > li[2]:
                finaltemp = [lr[0], lr[1], lr[2]]
                n = +1    
                key = 'Bad' + str(n)
                def t() : return {key : finaltemp}
                Finallist.update(t())
print(Finallist)
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that we can execute to reproduce your problem. Your code will not run because of missing variable definitions (`df`, `Finallist`, possibly more), and is therefore not a minimal **reproducible** example. Since we cannot reproduce your problem, we cannot say for sure why it happens and how to fix it.

Comment: I assume you actually want everything from the `Liststr1A` statement onward to be un-indented so it is not part of the `for` loop.  You don't want to do that processing until the lists are completely formed.

Comment: What are `col1`, `col2`, `col3`, and `col4`?  Your data has named columns, but not those names.

Comment: I updated the post. Thanks for the knowledge @PranavHosangadi. I am new to stack.

Answer (score 0):

This simplifies your final loop, which as I said should be at the left margin, not indented one step:

```
Liststr1A = Liststr1[:10]
for li in Liststr2:
    for lr in Liststr1A:
        if lr[0] == li[0] and lr[1] == li[1] and lr[2] > li[2]:
            Finallist['Bad'+str(len(FinalList)+1)] = lr[:]
print(Finallist)
```

It's not clear to me why you want `Finallist` to be a dictionary, since you want incrementing keys.  Why not just make it a list and use `Finallist.append`?

Comment: Thank you. The reason for the dict. was to get more experience with dict. I tried the `Finallist.append(l[:])` and it works as well. However, now I am getting a list that is much larger than my original dataframe. I think it is because of the two nested for loops.

Comment: I cant edit a comment??. I will have to get use to this.

Thank you. The reason for the dict. was to get more experience with dict. I tried the `Finallist.append(l[:])` and it works as well. However, now I am getting a list that is much larger than my original dataframe. I think it is because of the two nested for loops.
`for li in Liststr2:
    for lr in Liststr1A:`
I think the above is iterating every `li` over `lr` more than once. There is something I am missing. I am still trying to get a better understanding of iterating list in this nested format.

Comment: @MrC. you can edit a comment for up to 5 minutes after you first submit it.